Renaming file in a long-path in Windows 11 in GUI does not work, when programmatically it does
I have problems renaming a file in a long-path in the GUI on Windows 11 v23H2, while programmatically it can be renamed. How can I tell Windows to allow me do the renaming in the GUI?

G:\ is a google-drive unit mounted by the desktop google drive application and the path is:
G:\Mi unidad\07 Support\2022\HelloTrip (xavi - highlight-iconography)\HelloTrip Full-Team\51 Offices Shared\Oficina 0001 - Antí - Ctra. de Molinos0\2024\Funnel 2024-05may venta\Trip Requests\028 Lead Name\Iteración 2 - 7-jun\Grecia Clásica Jul 2pax m_M9DxFd.pdf

 


If I do a single-click in the usual Windows folder interface to rename it, when I press Enter, the changes get discarded and the file is not renamed:  
Instead:

If I go to the Google Drive Web UI:   
I can rename it:   
File gets properly renamed in Windows without touching anything:   
I can open the file normally in Win11 by double clicking on the renamed file

Note:
I already have the LongPathsEnabled key in the reg-edit set to 1. But even with that, still this fails.

Note:
As I stated, programmatically it works. The same way the Drive Client can rename the file, also does the git-bash for example to rename the file by the command line. The problem is in the GUI
Example renaming a file by bash:

The file got properly renamed.

Windows has always had this issue within the GUI and I'm unsure if this has been modified in Windows 11. Long paths >256 characters can always be modified via CLI, however I'm unsure if a GUI method exists; there are questions/answers on Superuser that address this, so it may be beneficial to try the site search to see if any of them provide a solution that would work for you. If a CLI method is the only one, and you're renaming files/directories consistently x number of nested directories down, creating a user environment variable for that x nested directory would make doing so via CLI easier

There is a registry key that removes the limit on long names/paths so it will work in File Explorer. It is default off, because some legacy applications don't like it, but you can change that key using regedit. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled. Change value to 1 to enable (reboot needed). If it doesn't exist you can make the key yourself (REG_DWORD) and set it to value 1

BTW, it's handy to have a directory on a drive with a short name, such as c:\tmp. That folder can be useful when downloading files with long names, to help avoid the long path issue.

you can also assign a mount point to a subdirectory, which will shorten the name considerably: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive

@Tonny I already had Key that set to 1. But still it fails. I'm going to edit my post to clarify.

@DrMoishePippik I am doing this already. I move the files to a tmp folder, I rename, I then movem them back to drive. But this has an issue: It looses the metadata "creation time" in Drive as it thinks it's a new file.

@Yorik I think the link you suggest is the the opposite. You have a drive and you want to make it appear "in a folder" so if you write to /some/nice/path you write to disk 1 and if you write to /some/nice/other-path you write to disk 2. The opposite would be helpful in this case, but not the link you share.

@JW0914 yes, if I open a git-bash it can also rename the file. As I said, programmatically it works. Ie: the internal windows API works (the same API will be called both by git-bash than the google drive clients, will probably be the "operating system move" operation). I'm going to edit the post to reflect that I can rename by bash too.

@JW0914 nevertheless I don't get how user environment variables would help in making the GUI work.

@XaviMontero Please re-read my comment

@JW0914 Humm... are you referring if I have to "systematically have to go and do it in bash"? This is also one method I'm currently using, but I don't get what role an env var would play. I use git-bash and I have a context menu. I just click "Git bash here" and I'm inside the directory. Thing is I want to make something "simple" for people working with me and I can't ask them even to invoke a bash to rename a file.

@XaviMontero No - I'd try site search to see if another solution besides a Registry key exists "...I'm unsure if a GUI method exists; there are questions/answers on Superuser that address this, so it may be beneficial to try the site search to see if any of them provide a solution that would work for you. If a CLI method is the only one, and you're renaming files/directories consistently x number of nested directories down, creating a user environment variable for that x nested directory would make doing so via CLI easier"

You are right, I posted the wrong link. I think there are multiple ways of doing this, but you can try the subst command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst
